# Loading gif while loading iframe

Tags: html, iframe, loading, gif

I have tried searching on Google to help this problem, but I just can't seem to find anything that works.
On a website I have made for a friend is there an iframe so you can read an PDF from the website, but it takes a long time to load the iframe. So, I want a little loading gif to appear when entering the website and when the iframe has loaded it should disappear again.
I have come close but it just won't work correctly. This is what I got.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server"> 
<div id="divLoading"> 
    <img src="/images/Gear.gif" alt="" height="42px" width="42px"/> 
</div> 
<div id="divFrameHolder" style="display:none"> 
    <iframe id="iframewebpage" runat="server" src="https://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://vandvaerk.smidstrup.net/documents/nfsv/Nyt%20fra%20SV%202017-2.pdf&embedded=true" style="width:100%; height:20%; overflow:hidden; scrolling=no; z-index:1;" frameborder="0" onload="hideLoading()" frameborder="0"> 

    </iframe> 
</div> 
</form>
```

But now i won't load the iframe and just keep showing the loading gif.

Comment: where is your `hideLoading()` function ?

Comment: In the iframe. onload="hideLoading()